# Bit Rotation operation

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to make the Bit rotation operation reversible? I mean, if there is an image X (size 256 * 256 *3) then on doing bit rotation, image Y is obtained. Then on subjecting Y to a bit rotation, we get back image X. Also, How to tackle the bit overflow so that there is no information loss.

Comment: Rotation doesn't lose information, it just shifts it around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I've taken the code I posted below and refined it into [a complete function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30679-bitrotate) with error-checking, help documentation, and the ability to operate on arrays of unsigned integers *and* double-precision variables just like the related built-in function [BITSHIFT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bitshift.html). I suggest using the newer version I link to above instead of the older version posted below.

---

MATLAB does not have a built-in bit rotation function, and the [BITSHIFT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bitshift.html) function will drop bits that overflow. However, you could implement your own bit rotation function based on the [existing bit operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/f16-42340.html#f16-7080). Here's a simple first-pass version I threw together (sans error-checking):

```
function data = bit_rotate(data,nBits)
  dataBits = log2(double(intmax(class(data)))+1);  %# Number of bits in data
  nBits = rem(nBits,dataBits);  %# No need to rotate by dataBits bits or more
  if nBits == 0  %# No bit rotation needed, just return
    return
  end
  shiftedData = bitshift(data,nBits);              %# Bit shift the data
  lostData = bitxor(data,bitshift(shiftedData,-nBits));  %# Find the lost bits
  rotatedData = bitshift(lostData,nBits-sign(nBits)*dataBits);  %# Rotate them
  data = shiftedData+rotatedData;  %# Add the rotated bits to the shifted bits
end
```

And here's some test data:

```
>> B = uint8(208);     %# An unsigned 8-bit integer value
>> disp(dec2bin(B,8))  %# Display the bit pattern of B
11010000
>> disp(dec2bin(bit_rotate(B,2),8))   %# Rotate left by 2 bits
01000011
>> disp(dec2bin(bit_rotate(B,-2),8))  %# Rotate right by 2 bits
00110100
```

Note that `bit_rotate` will also operate on any size matrix input for `data` as long as it's an unsigned integer type.

Comment: @gnovice,the forward bit rotation works fine. However, i worked it with a gray scale image and it was not possible to recover the original image through the same logic!!How to go about it?

Comment: @gavisha: I have no way of knowing what went wrong without seeing what you are doing. The images I tested work fine. For example: `img = imread('cameraman.tif'); rotimg = bit_rotate(img,2); figure; imshow(rotimg); recimg = bit_rotate(rotimg,-2); figure; imshow(recimg);`

Comment: I did exactly the same although I chose 10 bits instead of 2 bits. Is it possible to rotate by say m bits, if the size is m*n?

Comment: @gavisha: Is your image 8-bit? If so, you shouldn't rotate by more than 8 bits, since that's pointless. You would just be rotating the bits back to their original position, and then even further. In other words, rotating 8 bits by 10 is equivalent to rotating by 2. I'll add a correction for this case to my code above.

Comment: @gnovice. Ok this makes some sense. So if the size of the image is 512*512*3(RGB) then what are the maximum number of bits which can be rotated in this case?Lastly,correct me if i am wrong in concluding that Bitshift is not reversible but there is something known as cyclic bit shift and the code which you have provided is bit rotate operation using the existing bit shift.

Comment: @gavisha: The *size* (i.e. number of elements) is different than the *type* (i.e. number of bits *per* element). You can use the function [CLASS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/class.html) to determine the [data type](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-43934.html) (`single`, `double`, `uint8`, etc.). You are right that BITSHIFT is not generally reversible, but the function I wrote above is.

Comment: @gnovice,then in this case it is safer that i first convert the image to double. Then can i use greater than 8 bits or still i am stuck up with the same  point?

Comment: @gavisha: The way I've written the function currently, it will only work on unsigned integer types. The bitwise operations in MATLAB are really only designed for these types. If you pass doubles to them I think they just end up trying to convert them to unsigned integers anyway to perform the operation. You can always convert an 8-bit type to a 16-bit type or larger though.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, bit rotation is reversible, just rotate the other way around by the same amount.

Wikipedia has nice info on how to implement it in C with basic bit shifts so that you don't get overflow:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift

And I suppose that if the operation is called "bit rotation" in Matlab, it surely doesn't overflow anyway.

Comment: Thank you Oli for the valuable input.